# Create unique getElement ID

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make `txtHint` unique or different each time it passes.  Any help on creating a counter or increment would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function showCustomer(str)
  {
      var xmlhttp;    
      if (str=="")
      {
           document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
           return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
           // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else
      {
           // code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
           {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","***.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/    , that link is for your future sanity.

Comment: do you want to change the `ID` of *txtHint*, or do you want to show at `innerHTML` what `str` has been sent and what came back from the server?

Comment: [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) - will get you a random number. If this is what you are searching for.

Comment: @Pilgerstorfer Franz I would like to see if I make ID unique of txtHint each time it passes

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    function showCustomer(str) {
        count++;
```

Then replace: `"txtHint"` with `"txtHint" + count`